# Plot element by element of a list in R

Tags: r

I saved 10 matrices of size 55 × 1 in a list (e.g. G). How can I plot element by element of the list? I would like to have 55 colored curves in a plot such that each curve has ten measurements.

```
set.seed(1)
G<-list()
for (i in 1:10){
  G[[i]]<-as.matrix(rnorm(55,0,1))
}
G
```

Thanks

Comment: A lot of things are possible, and so many of them need to be done in different ways. We can't know what your lists look like, so it's best if you make your question here reproducible. I also suggest you make it much smaller, perhaps 2-3 instead of 55. Once you know how to do it with 3, you can extend that to 55 fairly easily. Please provide sample data, either built programmatically, using existing R datasets, or providing the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is a small but big-enough sample of data for us to see.

Comment: It also helps to know what you've done so far. Part of it is to demonstrate your effort (b/c this is not a free-code-service), part of it is to neck down on what you need. For instance, is this base R, lattice, ggplot2, plotly, or something else?

Comment: Is anyone can help?

Comment: `matplot(t(do.call('cbind', G)), type = 'l')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
library(tidyverse)

invoke(cbind, G) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename_with(~paste0('col', seq_along(.))) %>% 
  mutate(row = factor(row_number())) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, unique(name))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(name, value, color = row, group = row) + 
  geom_line() + 
  guides(color=FALSE) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello,

Yes, but why col 10 is written after col1 in the plot?

Thanks

Comment: We need to arrange the factor levels for that. See the updated answer.